# Applescript leading colon in posix path

Tags: path, applescript, posix

I'm working on an applescript to save a pdf and then attach to an email, and I'm running into some strange behavior when attempting to attach the file after coercing to POSIX, which I'm assuming is what is causing the file not to be attached to the email:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
   activate
   open file theDOCX

   set outpath to ("Macintosh HD:Users:FAKEUSER:Desktop:automations:") & selectedrecipient & ".pdf"
   set activeDoc to active document
   save as activeDoc file name outpath file format format PDF
    
end tell


tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"...", content:"..."}
    
    tell newMessage
      make new recipient at newMessage with properties {email address:{address:selectedemail}}
      make new attachment with properties {file:outpath as POSIX file}
      
      delay 1
      
    make new recipient with properties {email address:{address:selectedccmail}} at end of cc recipients of 
    
    newMessage

    end tell

    open newMessage
    get newMessage
end tell
```

However, the file is not attaching, and I assume this is happening because there's a problem with the attachment path:

`log outpath` returns `Macintosh HD:Users:FAKEUSER:Desktop:automations:File Name.pdf`

`log outpath as POSIX file` returns `:Macintosh HD/Users/FAKEUSER/Desktop/automations/File Name.pdf`

Comment: Your `make new recipient` line after the *delay 1* has been truncated and will not compile. Can you flesh it out?

Comment: Other than that, two things… first, why use posix path at all? Does outlook require it for attachments? If you have a functioning file reference, why not just use it? Second, don't *coerce* to a posix path. Get the `posix path of outpath` and use that. You can read more about it in the Language Guide under [Aliases and Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW28). FWIW it looks like coercion shoehorns the volume name in front of the actual posix path.